# Proof that bilinear form is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form, coercive

Hi everyone I'm stuck with a proof and would be happy if anyone could help me out.

Let V be a Hilbert Space and $A:V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ symmetric, elliptic (coercive with constant $\alpha1$) and continuous (with constant $\alpha2$) bilinear form. We define of the space $X := V \times V$ the bilinear form $B : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
\begin{align*}
B((u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)) := A(u_1,v_1) + A(u_1,v_2)+ A(u_2,v_2) \  \forall (u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2) \in X
\end{align*}
Show that $B$ is coercive with constant ? .  Let $X_N\subset X $ be a linear subspace. Is $B$ also coercive on $X_N$?

Here is my try:

By definition $B$ is coercive on $X$ if

\begin{align*}
B(z,z)\geq \beta ||z||^2_X \ \forall z \in X, \ \beta \in \mathbb{R^+} 
\end{align*} 
If $z \in X$ arbitrary we have $z=(u,v)$ for some arbitrary $u,v \in V$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
B(z,z)=B((u,v),(u,v)) = A(u,u) + A(u,v)+ A(v,v)
\end{align*}

Now we can use that $A$ is coercive with constant $\alpha_1$ to get

\begin{align*}
B(z,z)=B((u,v),(u,v)) \geq \alpha_1||u||^2_V + \alpha_1||v||^2_V + A(u,v) \\ \geq (\alpha_1 + \frac{A(u,v)}{||u||^2_V + ||v||^2_V})(||u||^2_V + ||v||^2_V)
\end{align*}

Note that the left term defines a norm on $X$ so we have $||z||^2_X := (||u||^2_V + ||v||^2_V)$. This follows by the properties of the given $||\cdot||_V$ Norm on $V$. Therefore the coercivity constant $\beta$ of $B$ must be

\begin{align*}
\beta = \inf_{u,v \neq 0}(\alpha_1 + \frac{A(u,v)}{||u||^2_V + ||v||^2_V})
\end{align*}

If $B$ is coercive we need $\beta>0 \forall u,v \in V$.

Is this proof right so far? Now I dont know how to show that $\beta>0$ since I dont know about $A(u,v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can estimate 
$$
|A(u,v)| \le \alpha_2 \|u\|_V\|v\|_V \le \frac{\alpha_2}2(\|u\|_V^2 + \|v\|_V^2).
$$
Then you get coercivity of $A$ under the condition $\alpha_1 \ge\frac{\alpha_2}2$.

However, one can do better.
Since $A$ is symmetric,
it holds
$$
B(z,z) = A(u,u) + A(v,v) + \frac12 ( A(u,v) + A(v,u))\\
= \frac34 A(u+v,u+v) + \frac14 A(u-v,u-v).
$$
This decomposition is inspired by the eigenvalue decomposition of $\pmatrix{1&\frac12\\\frac12&1}$.
This proves
$$
B(z,z) \ge \frac{\alpha_1}4 ( 3\|u+v\|_V^2 + \|u-v\|_V^2).
$$
Since $\|u\| \le \frac12\| (u+v) + (u-v)\|$ and $\|v\|_V\le \frac12\|(u+v)-(u-v)\|_V$,
this proves that $B$ is coercive.

Comment: Now that answer made me happy since I got after some more thinking the same estimate like you stated. But by above its coercive without any restrictions. You stated also that the decomposition is related to the decomposition of $\pmatrix{1&\frac12\\\frac12&1}$, that is $\frac12\pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1}\pmatrix{\frac12&0\\0&\frac32}\pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1}$. Can you maybe explain a bit how I could think about this, so that I can next time come up with such an idea by myself.

Comment: Think of $A$ as a constant number and of $B$ as a quadratic from on $\mathbb R^2$.